# Goodness of Fit Test vs Testing RMSE

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, train

I have a bit of a broad question. It seems to be that there are two different approaches (Borrowing a bit of Breiman's Two Culture's paper) when it comes to testing if our data looks like our model.

1. Perform a goodness of fit test (Ala KS, Shapiro-Wilks)
2. Look at the loss function on a hold out test dataset.

While these two were presented in different contexts, is it fair to say that these two method are addressing the same question, "to check how well the model fits the data"? Are there times when one is preferred as a method of model evaluation over another?